# Gauss-Lobatto quadrature and nodal points for FEM

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, wave-equation, finite-element-method, quadrature

By using the Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto (LGL) quadrature formula (QF) and LGL nodal points one achives a diagonal mass-matrix for finite element problems. (More specifically, the spectral element method.)

Setting the $n$ quadrature points as nodal points, the polynomials of the ansatz and test space are of degree $n-1$.

The LGL QF is exact up to degree $2n-3$, but the mass-matrix should contain integrals of polynomials with degree $2n-2$.

**Is it normal for this kind of method, that each integral is inexact?**

**Is it possible at all to combine a DG-method with this ansatz of the spectral element method (SEM)?**

Any tips, pointers and literature will be appreciated.

Comment: I heard of Gauss-Legendre, but never of Lobatto. The high degree makes this method quite successful.

Comment: Head over to scicomp.se ... This question is more suited for that forum.

Comment: For others looking for the answer to this: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36559/gauss-lobatto-quadrature-and-nodal-points-for-fem